# Fatal error: Class 'Turnkeye_All_Helper_Data' not found in /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 520

Tags: magento

I FTP onestep checkout,
and enter magento admin cpanel to config it.it show as follow:
"Fatal error: Class 'Turnkeye_All_Helper_Data' not found in /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 520"
How to resolve this problem,Please help me,Thanks in advance.

Comment: OneStepCheckout is a commercial extension. If you have a legal version why don't you contact a developer?

Answer (score 1):

Check your module/etc/config.xml and identify the module name. 
Lets say it as "yyy" for example.

Now check your module/etc/system.xml and you can see [translate="label" module="xxx"]
Here module="xxx" should be module="yyy".

If it is not like that, please change. Logout after saving the details and login again. Check whether it works.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Mage.pgp at line 520 and put this code:

```
$file = fopen('data.txt','a+');
fwrite($file, $varFrom520Line."\n");
fclose($file);
```

Execute again, when this exception gives you go to you root folder and look for data.txt, the last line give you what Magento is searching and dont found.
And you should try put the right file on the right place to work, or look on code where are pointing to wrong path and fix it.